# What does Gideon say Barry Allen is the founding member of?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014, the-flash

When Barry, Cisco, and Caitlin first finds Gideon, she tells them about Barry saying "Founding member of..." but is interrupted by Barry. What exactly will Barry be the founding member of?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Most probably the Justice League.

From the preview comic for Episode 20 of Season 1 of the Flash, *The Trap* on the CW's twitter, they reveal that Gideon was cut-off after she said he was the" Founding member of the Justice..."

> [image: Preview comic for *The Trap*]
>   <sub>[From the CW twitter account](https://twitter.com/CW_TheFlash/status/591632828355325954)</sub>

Comment: I don't know if this will happen but i wonder how they are gonna present the Justice League in the CW-verse. Because the original leaguers do not exist in the same universe :| (nonetheless i hope they show something like this in the future seasons)

Comment: @Shreedhar Most online communities (reddit etc.) seem to agree this was simple fan-service and not actually anything to look forward to.

Comment: that's disappointing but its true.

Comment: @Shreedhar but Nora arc still dropping similar bombs and DCEU failing to make JL2 means arrowverse might get chance to do it

Answer (score -1):

Whereas Batman aka Bruce Wayne is the founder of the Justice League in the DCEU, Barry is the founder of the Justice League in the Arrowverse.  In fact, Barry has been the one behind at least two or three Arrowverse crossovers - as far as I know.  He was the one who arranged for both Team Flash and Team Arrow to battle Vandal Savage in the fall of 2015.  He was the one who arranged for Team Flash, Team Arrow, the Legends and Supergirl to form a team and battle the Dominators' invasion in the fall of 2016.  It was his wedding to Iris West that led to the gathering of the Arrowverse heroes to battle the Earth X villains in the fall of 2017.  And in the end it was Barry who literally formed the Justice League following Crisis, using STAR Labs' hangar as the League's future headquarters.

Comment: Could you edit this to give some evidence to this being the case?

Comment: She cited the the specific incidents where this happened. There's wanting evidence and then there's being ridiculous about wanting evidence.

Answer (score -2):

Founding member of the Justice League. In the comics he’s also a founding member. The founding members are the ones who were first in the Justice League so that would be: Batman, Superman, Wonder Women, The Flash, Green Lantern, Martian Manhunter/Cyborg.

Comment: Welcome to SF&F Lena. Although your answer is correct, I don't see anything to support your answer (check Edlothiad's answer, that can give you some ideas).

Comment: To add on to the above comment you can [edit] your answer to give some supporting evidence (i.e. quotes, comic panels, etc.) to help show why your answer is correct.